# What's proper way to insert a document using node API for MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using `node-mongo` for querying and inserting documents to a mongoDB database.

This is what I'm assuming for inserting:

```
collection.insert({}, function(err,insertedDocuments){

});
```

However for insertedDocuments I expect them to be the actual documents, but this is what insertedDocuments is always looking like:

```
{"ok":1,"n":1}
```

The important code to explain what I'm doing is:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/places', function (err, db) {

  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to database ... Will work with default places collection".inverse);
  places = db.collection('places');
  strings = db.collection('strings');

  app.route('/places').post(newPlaceController);

  app.listen(6190, function() {
    console.log('Express listening'.inverse);
  });
});

function newPlaceController (request,response) {

  console.log(request.body);
  var latitude = request.body.lat;
  var longitude = request.body.long;
  var name = request.body.name;

  var newPlace = getNewPlaceObject(name,latitude,longitude);  // This returns the object/document to be inserted

  places.insert(newPlace, function (err,createdPlace) {

    if (err)
      response.send(JSON.stringify(err),500);

    else {
      console.log(createdPlace);
      response.send(JSON.stringify(createdPlace),200);
    }
  });
}
```

Strangely, the log of createdPlace looks like this:

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  connection: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        timeout: [Object],
        parseError: [Object],
        connect: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     options: 
      { socketOptions: {},
        auto_reconnect: true,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 27017,
        cursorFactory: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        size: 5,
        disconnectHandler: [Object],
        bson: {},
        messageHandler: [Function],
        wireProtocolHandler: {} },
     id: 2,
     logger: { className: 'Connection' },
     bson: {},
     tag: undefined,
     messageHandler: [Function],
     maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
     port: 27017,
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     keepAlive: true,
     keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
     noDelay: true,
     connectionTimeout: 0,
     socketTimeout: 0,
     domainSocket: false,
     singleBufferSerializtion: true,
     serializationFunction: 'toBinUnified',
     ca: null,
     cert: null,
     key: null,
     passphrase: null,
     ssl: false,
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
     responseOptions: { promoteLongs: true },
     flushing: false,
     queue: [],
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 56,
        _bytesDispatched: 215,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        pipe: [Function],
        addListener: [Function: addListener],
        on: [Function: addListener],
        pause: [Function],
        resume: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     writeStream: null,
     buffer: null,
     sizeOfMessage: 0,
     bytesRead: 0,
     stubBuffer: null },
  ops: [ { name: 'OXXO', loc: [Object], _id: 553723a2a2c10c273605309a } ] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new record is at `createdPlace.ops[0]`. What you are calling `createdPlace` is not the new document, but a wrapper object the API docs call `result`. It contains metadata about the operation and then under the `ops` property array you can find the new documents.

Here's an excerpt from [the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/)

> The insert command will return a results object that contains several fields that might be useful.

- result Contains the result document from MongoDB
- ops Contains the documents inserted with added **_id** fields
- connection Contains the connection used to perform the insert

You might consider a more-convenient module such as [monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk) which will return the document to you. (Also recommended because in general the mongodb native API is so bad it's practically developer-hostile).

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious, how could `JSON.stringify` return only `{"ok":1,"n":1}`?

Comment: It doesn't. It returns exactly what the docs list: result, ops, connection. You're probably just misreading it because `connection` is so large, but at the top-level your variable (which is misnamed) `createdPlace` is the `results` object described by the documentation.

Comment: I'm returning `response.send(JSON.stringify(createdPlace),200);` and `{"ok":1,"n":1}` is what I can see ...

Comment: The `createdPlace` object probably provides a custom `toJSON` implementation that omits the transient `connection` property. I'd have to look at the source code to understand what happens to the `ops` property.

Comment: Yep, it should be that ... I just asked because I got so confused when I saw JSON.stringify returning something different than what the object was actually looking like.